# Setting of "respond_to" outside of action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, actionpack

I'd like to set "respond_to" part of action outside of action.

This is an example of how it should work:

```
def index
  ...
end

def show
  ...
end

response_for :index, :show do
  format.html do
     if empty_records?
       redirect_to root_path
     end
  end

  format.json do
    ...
  end
end
```

Earlier I used [response_for](https://github.com/ianwhite/response_for) gem for this but it isn't supported anymore. What solutions can you advice? I use Rails 4.2.

Comment: 1. Big part of legacy code was written in this way 2. DRY principle

Answer (score 0):

What about this?

```
def index
  ...
  return respond
end

def show
  ...
  return respond
end

private

def respond
  respond_to do |format|
    ...
  end
end
```

I use a similar pattern for building shared success and failure responses with my JSON APIs.

Comment: It's good solution, but it's more complicated comparing with code described in the question. Also I'd like to note that I have a big legacy project where described pattern used very often, so it will more easy implement "response_for" method.